# Application of Faraday's Law

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism, magnetic-fields

I know from my involvement with the Mathematics StackExchange site that this is not supposed to be about helping people with their homework.

But... my daughter has asked me to help her with her A Level Physics homework. As a teacher of A Level Maths and Further Maths and someone who studied A Level Physics a long time ago I'm supposed to explain the principles and show where the different bits of the calculation fit together.

This one has me stumped. I thought it was to do with Lenz's Law and I understand the hand-waving arguments about magnets falling through copper pipes, but I can't find out how to do the actual calculations...

So what I'm looking for is the right formulae to use in this application. I am very happy to put all the bits together once I understand what the bits are.

Here's her question:

[image]

Comment: Hint: use Faraday's Law.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments, Lenz's law is only a qualitative statement, while [Faraday's law](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faraday%27s_law_of_induction) is the appropriate quantitative statement. It says that a changing magnetic flux $\Phi_\mathrm{enc}$ induces an EMF ("electromotive force", i.e. a kind of "voltage around the ring"
$$ \mathcal{E} = \oint \vec{E} \cdot d\vec{\ell} = -\frac{d\Phi_\mathrm{enc}}{dt}. $$
Calculate the rate of change of the flux, set it equal to the EMF, then use Ohm's law to find the current.

Comment: So is the rate of change of flux simply the flux density multiplied by the area in this case?

Comment: Yes, that's correct.

Comment: Thank you very much!

Comment: Rate of change of flux is _rate of change_ of magnetic field (flux density = magnetic field) times the area.

Answer (score 1):

Lenz's law states: 
$$
\varepsilon = - \frac{d\Phi}{dt}
$$
Where $\Phi$ is the magnetic flux, and $\varepsilon$ the electromotive force. However, the problem gives us not the change in the magnetic flux, but the change in *flux density*, i.e. the magnetic field $B$. You can rewrite Lenz's law as:
$$
\varepsilon = -\frac{d}{dt} \int B \cdot dA,   
$$
Where $A$ is the surface enclosed by the copper ring.

Comment: Thanks. With what you and the other person have said I think I have it.

Comment: Technically, this is Faraday's law, not Lenz's law per se. Lenz's law says that the induced current produces a magnetic field that "tries to" compensate for the for the change in flux.